# Project Panama: can't find function

Tags: java, project-panama

I'm trying Project Panama (foreign function interface) of Java 19 with following code to read the current directory on Windows 10 (as a simple example). This is the begin of my code:

```
final Linker linker = Linker.nativeLinker();
final SymbolLookup linkerLookup = linker.defaultLookup();
final SymbolLookup systemLookup = SymbolLookup.loaderLookup();
final SymbolLookup symbolLookup = name -> systemLookup.lookup(name)
                                 .or(() -> linkerLookup.lookup(name));
final MemorySegment addr = symbolLookup.lookup("GetCurrentDirectory")
                          .orElse(null);
...
```

The problem is, when debugging `addr` is `null`, so it looks like it can't find the method by this name. Do I somehow need to tell the lookup in what DLL it should look for this function (for a test with `printf` this was not necessary)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Do I somehow need to tell the lookup in what DLL it should look for this function

Yes, you have to load the library that contains `GetCurrentDirectory`, which is `Kernel32` (according to the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-getcurrentdirectory#requirements)):

```
System.loadLibrary("Kernel32");
```

After loading a library with `System::load` or `System::loadLibrary`, it can be found using the loader lookup (i.e. `SymbolLookup.loaderLookup()`). See [the documentation](https://download.java.net/java/early_access/jdk20/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/foreign/SymbolLookup.html#loaderLookup()):

> Returns a symbol lookup for symbols in the libraries associated with
> the caller's class loader.
>
> A library is associated with a class loader `CL` when the library is
> loaded via an invocation of `System.load(String)` or
> `System.loadLibrary(String)` from code in a class defined by `CL`. ...

Note that `System::loadLibrary` also requires the directory that contains the library to be listed in the `java.library.path` system property (you will get an exception if it's not). For `Kernel32` this should be `C:\Windows\System32`

> (for a test with printf this was not necessary)?

The reason it works for `printf` is because you are using the `defaultLookup` of the `nativeLinker` which can find all the symbols in the [standard C library](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/header). `GetCurrentDirectory` is not a part of that library though.

---

Furthermore, it looks like `GetCurrentDirectory` is defined as `__inline`, which means you can not link against it dynamically, as the symbol/function is simply not present in `Kernel32.dll`, AFAICT:

```
> dumpbin.exe /EXPORTS C:\Windows\System32\kernel32.dll | sls GetCurrentDirectory

        555  22A 0001F010 GetCurrentDirectoryA
        556  22B 00018CA0 GetCurrentDirectoryW
```

Instead, you have to look up and call `GetCurrentDirectoryA` for `char`s or `GetCurrentDirectoryW` for `wchar_t`s directly:

```
System.loadLibrary("Kernel32");
SymbolLookup loaderSyms = SymbolLookup.loaderLookup();
MemorySegment addr = loaderSyms.lookup("GetCurrentDirectoryA").orElseThrow();
// use 'addr'
```